# Open images from online folder

Tags: java, android, image, directory, universal-image-loader

I want to show images from a folder that I am hosting on my own website. But I can't seem to get it to work. Currently I can load these images perfectly fine if I use a line of code for each image. But I want to load the images from bulk by targetting said folder, but I can't seem to get this to work.

I am trying to make this work with the Universal Image Loader library. And I am trying to show them all in a gridview.

instead of loading www.mywebsite.com/images/1.jpg
I want to load the whole images folder at once if its possible.

Is this doable with the universal image loader library or do I need to use something else?

Universal Image Loader: https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader

Comment: Depends really on how the server side is set up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a quick look at the Universal image loader library it does not support bulk image loading from a zip file.

Supported URIs are:

```
String imageUri = "http://example.com/image.png"; // from Web
String imageUri = "file:///mnt/sdcard/image.png"; // from SD card
String imageUri = "content://media/external/audio/albumart/13"; // from content provider
String imageUri = "assets://image.png"; // from assets 
String imageUri = "drawable://" + R.drawable.image; // from drawables (only images, non-9patch)
```

You can either load a zip file with e.g. HttpURLConnection yourself, unzip it and use the images or load images one by one.